# <script> not working in php environment

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a javascript that calls for pagination from datatables.net I have tried running in on a full html file and it works like a charm. The trial code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
        font-size:13px;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #E6E6FF;
}
td {
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #E0F0FF;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>

            <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>


            </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

But however when i tried running it in a php environment, the pagination from the script did not appear. What is causing it not to work? Because I have sql queries in the php code. I print the queries into a html table. So it should work like the trial code right? Some extract from the php code is as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
        font-size:13px;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #E6E6FF;
}
td {
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #E0F0FF;
}
</style>
    </head>

<body>

<?php

echo "<table id='example' class='display' width='100%'>

<tr>
<th>Nama Badan</th>
<th>Negeri</th>
<th>Jenis Sukan</th>
<th>Kategori</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row['NamaBadan'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['STATE_NAME'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['JenisSukan'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['KategoriSukantext'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['Status'] ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: src="//datatables.net/ not valid URL use http:// not just //

Comment: Is there an error on the JavaScript console in the browser?  When you examine the resulting markup from the PHP script, in what way does it differ from the original?  JavaScript has *no knowledge* that there's any PHP server-side code, so the fact that it's "a PHP environment" makes no difference.

Comment: @Dave: Incorrect, beginning a URL with `//` is valid.

Comment: `//datatables.net` is a valid source, as it automatically uses the location protocol scheme, either `http:` or `https:`. probably you should do so with the jquery script too, because if you use https, newer firefox will block "active content".

Comment: That is what I understand too. There should be no problem. But it seems when I try to echo the <table>, the pagination just doesn't seem to work. By that I mean, the table works. But the pagination doesn't.

Comment: it may "work" but its horrible practice to not correctly define the protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to:

```
echo "<table id='example' class='display' width='100%'>

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nama Badan</th>
<th>Negeri</th>
<th>Jenis Sukan</th>
<th>Kategori</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `<thead>` tags  around the first `<tr>` to let Datatables load its object.

Answer (score 0):

That code might not work beacuse this kind of echo won't work:

```
echo "<table id='example' class='display' width='100%'>";
```

You're writing html attribute with ' instead of ". Try this:

```
echo '<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">';
```

Comment: This doesn't makes any difference, even with IE 6. Only issue: do a single space between last single or double quote and greater-than sign, like width="100%" >, as sometimes IE doesn't recognize the symbol.

There is a difference in php while using double instead of single quotes, you may prefer to use always double quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php